# I want to make a request using OkHttpClient and I want to change the URL if the response is not successful

Tags: java, api, exception, try-catch, okhttp

So I am requesting an API call to search records by phone number. If the response is unsuccessful, I want to change the URL to search the record by name. In order to send the request and obtain the response we have a try catch clause. My only thought would be to repeat the request and response using a new URL inside the original catch clause . Can anyone inform me how I should go about changing the URL and making a new request if the original request catches an exception. Here is my snippet of code that requests to search by phone number. And the stackstrace which is evident because the request fails.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build();
String phone = DNC_List[i].getNumber();
Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Leads/search?phone=" + phone)
        .method("GET", null).addHeader("Authorization", "Zoho-oauthtoken 1000.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx")
        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .addHeader("Cookie",
                "1a9a93sda653=12a340a9c5d3e8sfd2161d0b; crmcsr=43sdv9-07ads5-4549-a166-0aad54gw6b; _zcsr_tmp=435e5334fa5-4549-a1667s889s8cf6b; JSESSIONID=54FF23B98378EBB45E4FA411823B5E61")
        .build();
System.out.println("request = " + request);
try {
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    String responseBody = response.body().string();
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement je = parser.parse(responseBody);
    String prettyJsonString = gson.toJson(je);
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(prettyJsonString);

    System.out.println(i + "PrettyJson = " + prettyJsonString + "\n______________end of string________");
    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) json.get("data");
    JSONObject data0 = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(0);
    JSONObject owner = (JSONObject) data0.get("Owner");
    String id = owner.getString("id");
    String id2 = data0.getString("id");
    DNC_ID[i] = id2;
    System.out.println("DNC_ID[" + i + "]= " + DNC_ID[i]);

} catch (Exception e) {
    // Need to search leads by name if phone number does not work
    // How to change the URL to search by name
    System.out.println("Entered catch clause: index = " + i);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output for the failed code:

```
request = Request{method=GET, url=https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Leads/search?phone=1234567890, tags={}}
    Entered catch clause: index = 0
    org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
            at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:507)
            at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:222)
            at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:406)
            at com.App.main(App.java:103)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is failing to parse some JSON it doesn't appear like it's necessarily because the search returned zero results. If that were true it would return an empty array. Double check your JSON shapes and make sure they match what the API returns.

Also, it appears like you are mixing and matching two different JSON libraries. The built in Android objects such as `JSONObject` and Google's GSON pick one and stick with one don't mix and match them.

To aid in debugging this use OkHttps built in logging system and experiment with setting different logger levels.

Also to help debug you can set up [OkHttp debug logging with an interceptor](https://www.stubbornjava.com/posts/okhttpclient-logging-configuration-with-interceptors).

```
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpUtil.class);
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging =
    new HttpLoggingInterceptor((msg) -> {
        logger.debug(msg);
    });
logging.setLevel(Level.BODY);

client.addNetworkInterceptor(logging);
```